# Asked about jumping into line

Tags: c#, loops

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter x and y:");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("chose math : plus , minus , mutiple , devide :");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            int z;
            string name="";
            if (choice == "plus")  
            {
                z=x+y;
                name="+";
            }  
            else if (choice == "minus")  
            {
                z=x - y;
                name="-";
            }
            if (choice == "mutiply")  
            {
                z = x * y;
                name = "*";
            }
            else
            {
                z=x / y;
                name = "/";
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", x, name, y, z);
            Console.WriteLine("More math ? <Y/N> ");
            string choice1 =Console.ReadLine();
            if ((choice1 == "y") || (choice1 == "Y") ) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("asd");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what method to use in this situation. As you can see the last line of my program say "more math yes or no" so I already coded the progarm to doing nothing when i press N, but I don't know how do I jump back to the first line. If I press Y > I want my program to jump back into `console.writeline("enter x and y")`

Comment: You also have an error in your if statements. The division will be done also for plus and minus.

Comment: @GrantWinney : example please ... also my if statements work fine

Answer (score 1):

Use a `do / while` loop.

You know you want the logic to run through at least once. After that, prompt the user to see if they want to play again. If they choose "Y", the condition is `true` and it loops again.

```
do
{
    // all your program logic
    Console.WriteLine("More math ? <Y/N> ");
} while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");
```